# Optimising dictionary key generation/lookup in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, hash, compression, md5, crc32

My program will contain a lot of references to a few large python dictionaries. The dictionaries use as keys fairly long strings (often +100 characters). I need to often check the presence of a key in these dictionaries. And very often it would be for the **same string** as it passes through the flow of the script.

Checking the presence of a key in a dictionary is O(1). However, producing a hash of a string (which is what a dictionary would do) is O(N) where N is the length of the string. Since I need to do these checks very often for the same string I was wondering if there a way to optimise this hash re-generation? I was thinking along the lines of (pseudo-code follows):

```
(1) receive a long string as an input
(2) create a short version of the string, e.g. by using MD5 or CRC32
(3) use the short version as a key
```

Does this make sense?

If yes, what sort of compression/hashing would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I was over-engineering the problem.

I was trying to mimic the structure of a RDBMS table so was looking for unique primary keys. These were the long strings that I was thinking of hashing. And I was looking for an efficient ways to do the hashing.

But the solution was much simpler -  I found the equivalent of an auto-increment PK. In python you can do this with *itertools.count()*. So, instead of using the original long strings I started using *itertools.count()*. It is not an ideal solution but it solved the problem.